# Could not enter data: Unknown column 'emp_salary' in 'field list'

Tags: php, mysql

Here is the code that causes the error I pasted in the title. I am pretty sure the error comes from the query but cannot figure it out.

The last thing I have tried is the "real escape" function you can see here and that I found as a response in some other questions of the same type; still the same error. I am starting with coding and might just be stupid... anyways, thanks for your help!

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['add']))
{
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = 'boom';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

if(! get_magic_quotes_gpc() )
{
   $emp_name = addslashes ($_POST['emp_name']);
   $emp_address = addslashes ($_POST['emp_address']);
   $emp_salary = addslashes ($_POST['emp_salary']);
}
else
{
   $emp_name = $_POST['emp_name'];
   $emp_address = $_POST['emp_address'];
   $emp_salary =  $_POST['emp_salary'];
}


$sql = "INSERT INTO employee (emp_name,emp_address,emp_salary) 
   VALUES('".mysql_real_escape_string($emp_name)."','".mysql_real_escape_string($emp_address)." ','".mysql_real_escape_string($emp_salary)." ')";

mysql_select_db('test_db');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "Entered data successfully\n";
mysql_close($conn);
}
else
{
?>
```

Comment: Can we see the table definition for `employee`?

Comment: Like the error message already told you: `emp_salary` is not a column in the table `employee`. Double-check for the correct name of the field/column, remove any typos.

Comment: `addslash`.... hmmm I know what your next question will be.... **Why / appearing in my datas?** only matter is when?

Comment: Please look into using parametrized SQL queries rather than going through all that `mysql_real_escape_string` noise.  http://bobby-tables.com/php.html has examples.

Answer (score 1):

create the column named `emp_salary` in respective table.

You must not use `mysql_` function family as you are more prone to SQL attacks with these.

Either use mysqli or better to use PDO